# How to get the necessary data from an API

Tags: json, xml, xquery, oxygenxml

I need to make a school project in Oxygen, using the following API: https://potterapi.com/
I wrote a function to get all the necessary JSON data from the API:

let $apikey := fn:doc("potterapi.key")/apikey/string()
return
    map {
        "characters": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters?key=" || $apikey),
        "houses": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/houses?key=" || $apikey),
        "spells": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters?key=" || $apikey)
    }

I also made an another xml scheme where I define the apikey, and i need to get the data in json format.
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? You said your code gets all the necessary JSON data, is the only problem left to serialize it as JSON? Then use `serialize(let $apikey := fn:doc("potterapi.key")/apikey/string() return map { "characters": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters?key=" || $apikey), "houses": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/houses?key=" || $apikey), "spells": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters?key=" || $apikey) }, map { 'method' : 'json', 'indent' : true() })`.

Comment: Yes, the code should get the necessary data, but i don't know how to "set up" oxygen to get the output as a JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serialize an XQuery 3.1 map as JSON with XQuery 3.1 you have two options, either use the serialize function

```
serialize(
  let $apikey := fn:doc("potterapi.key")/apikey/string() return map { "characters": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters?key=" || $apikey), "houses": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/houses?key=" || $apikey), "spells": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters?key=" || $apikey) },
  map { 'method' : 'json', 'indent' : true() }
)
```

or use the needed XQuery option declarations

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'json';
declare option output:indent 'yes';

let $apikey := fn:doc("potterapi.key")/apikey/string() return map { "characters": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters?key=" || $apikey), "houses": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/houses?key=" || $apikey), "spells": fn:json-doc("https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters?key=" || $apikey) }
```

Comment: Thanks you Martin, but what should i do with the apikey? Do i have to create an XML file with the apikey in it and make a transformation?

Comment: I thought you had created an XML file named `potterapi.key` with an element `<apikey>...</apikey>` that contains your key(instead of the `...`) and that you are reading in with `let $apikey := fn:doc("potterapi.key")/apikey/string()`.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But when I Want to make the transformation, the Oxygen gives me some kind of Saxon error.

Comment: Well, then edit your question and describe exactly what you are doing in oXygen, which version of it you use, which version of Saxon you have selected, and of course, which error exactly you get.

Comment: Hey Martin, i made it. I don't know why but it did not worked with the serialize function, but it worked with the XQuery option declaration. Thank you again, it helped me a lot !

Comment: Hey Martin, sorry for bothering you, are you familiar with JSON Scheme?

Comment: @ZoltanBilcsik, no, I am not.